# How do I switch between while loops before the current loop finishes? IR Remote + LED's

Tags: programming, ir, wireless

I have a project that requires rotation of a tank tread. I've simulated LED's to go off in a rotation using an IR Remote. I want to stop the clockwise rotation halfway through so I can immediately rotation counterclockwise.

Unfortunately, my code waits until after the complete rotation (or the complete while/if loop) to move into the ccw rotation loop. How do I code this to immediately switch between loops?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 10;
int Switch = 10;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

  irrecv.enableIRIn();         // Start the receiver
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
    Serial.println(results.value);
    irrecv.resume();           // Receive the next value
  }

  while (results.value == 16615543)     // button 2: clockwise rotation
  {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
  }

  while (results.value == 16580863)     //power button - break other loops and wait for next IR transmission
  {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }

  while (results.value == 16619623)     // button 8: ccw rotation
  {
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your parenthetic comment in the original edit, the thing you were missing formatting-wise was sequence of three backticks to quote the code.  There is built-in help through an icon (a question mark with a circle) in the upper right when you're editing.  I ran your code through an auto-formatter and manually collapsed a lot of the double-spacing.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I code this to immediately switch between loops?

You don't. You remove the loops. You don't want them - they can never end, since there is no way for the results to change between iterations.

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how IR remotes work. There can be no "while" since a remote sends a signal either just once per button press, or repeatedly while the button is held down, depending on the function the button is supposed to perform.

Instead all you can do is "If the button has been pressed then do something". There's no "It's currently pressed" or "It's been released", only "I got a signal that it's pressed".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Majenko's answer, what you should use is a so called State engine.

First you define an enum:

```
enum EState { Off, Clockwise, CounterClockwise };

EState _state;
```

In `setup` you set  `_state` to some default value.

In `loop` you check for button changes, and set the state accordingly.

Then you act on the state:

```
switch (_state)
{
case EState::Off:
    {
        // Switch all off
        for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++)
        {
            digitalWrite(n, LOW);
        }
    }
    break;

case EState::Clockwise:
    ... See below

case EState::CounterClockwise:
    ... Similar as above
}
```

For the Clockwise and CounterClockwise states, you have to keep a variable, that increases every 100 ms, resets itself when going to the new state.

Depending on the step value, you do something. e.g. for the first two clockwise steps:

```
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
delay(500);                // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)

digitalWrite(9, LOW);
delay(1000);               // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
```

you can make a switch like this inside the case you already have (or better: create a new function):

```
switch (_step)
{
case 0: // 0 ms
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    break;

case 5: // 500 ms
    delay(1000);

...
```

Note it is a bit more clean to create a sort of hash/array but the above should work too. You can increase `_step` every 100 ms or only when the (counter)clockwise states are active.